# Core Data predicate not matching boolean attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass with a boolean attribute. It's non-optional, with `NO` as the default. In the model interface it is declared as `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * deleted;`, in the implementation, `@dynamic deleted;`.

It is persisting correctly if I check the underlying SQLite file. However, I am finding that fetches with predicates querying this attribute do not work correctly. I have tried `deleted == YES`, `deleted == %@` with `@YES` and `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`, and indeed `deleted == 1`. I've even tried using a single equals sign out of pure voodoo paranoia. Nothing works.

This is causing a bug in my code using an `NSFetchedResultsController`. The full predicate is currently `(list = %@) OR (deleted = YES)`. I change `deleted` to `@YES`, change the value of `list`, and the controller issues an unexpected `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete`, despite the object still logically matching the predicate.

There's no doubting it *doesn't* match the predicate however (at least in memory), as I've tested with:

```
BOOL matchesBefore = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate evaluateWithObject:thing];
// do stuff, setting thing.deleted = @YES, thing.list = @"something else"
BOOL matchesAfter = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate evaluateWithObject:thing];
NSAssert(matchesBefore && matchesAfter, @"Should still match");
```

Interestingly, in the debugger, the attribute is displayed as `deleted = 0;`, however printing the actual `NSNumber` yields `(NSNumber *) $5 = 0x07455ec0 1`. Again, in the underlying database, the value is stored correctly as '1'.

So I'm greatly confused. Any ideas? This is iOS, on 5.x both in the simulator and on device.

Comment: Sounds like a collision with reserved names, some deep lying undocumented (?) use of the keyword `deleted`. (Wouldn't be strange in the context of a `NSManagedObject`, or maybe in `NSFetchedResultsController`.) Try to change the name of the field to something else.

Comment: Excellent instincts - this does indeed solve it. Certainly `NSManagedObject` responds to `isDeleted`, so I suppose I should have been more paranoid about that. Thank you, and by all means write this up as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: I can't find a list of reserved attribute names anywhere, beyond obviously `description` and some indication that `version` is also forbidden. If anyone knows of such a resource, I'd love to have it linked from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a collision with reserved names, some deep lying undocumented (?) use of the keyword **deleted**. (Wouldn't be strange in the context of a `NSManagedObject`, or maybe in `NSFetchedResultsController`.) Try to change the name of the field to something else.